# R zipfR and Wolfram Mathematica return different values for inverse regularized incomplete gamma function

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, poisson

zipfR library function Rgamma.inv and wolfram mathematica function InverseGammaRegularized return different values for some inputs. What is the mathematical difference between the two?

My preference is to use R, and my goal is to use a function in R that outputs the Poisson parameter for an empirical CDF. The wolfram alpha function does this well, but Rgamma.inv does not. Below are code examples first in R and then wolfram mathematica.

```
Rgamma.inv(11, ppois(10, 10.66852))
#returns 10.66852 which is correct

Rgamma.inv(101, ppois(100, 60* 20/9))
#returns 73.83016, not 133.33
```

```js
InverseGammaRegularized[11,0.5]
#returns 10.66852 which is correct

InverseGammaRegularized[101,0.001543465] 
#returns 133.33 which is correct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. Its only that you are computing the lower regularized gamma when using R but you are computing the upper regularized gamma when using wolfram mathematica. You are comparing two different results. Thus wont be the same. To obtain the same results, ensure you compute the upper regularized gamma using R also and compare:

using R:

computing the upper regularized gamma:

```
Rgamma.inv(11, ppois(10, 10.66852),lower = FALSE)
[1] 10.66852
Rgamma.inv(101, ppois(100, 60* 20/9),lower = FALSE)
[1] 133.3333
```

These are the results given above

Comment: yes.  Also note that `Rgamma.inv()` is a thin wrapper for `stats::qgamma()`; `qgamma(x=ppois(100, 60* 20/9), shape=101, lower.tail=FALSE)` gives the same result ...